# How to plot a graph showing the rolls of a dice and the frequency?

Tags: excel, charts

I have a a column of data which tells me the outcome after a roll of the dice.

In Excel how do I plot a graph which shows frequency of the outcomes on the y axis and numbers between `1` and `6` on the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table to create this graph.

Insert tab > PivotTable

Row Labels (lower left box) should be the dice roll value.  Values (lower right box) should be the count of the dice roll value.  Lastly create a bar chart from the pivot table.